# Find webparts title matching pattern

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I would like to remove web parts on a page with titles matching to a pattern. I understand that the `-Title` parameter of the `Get-PnPWebpart` method does accept wildcards. So I tought that I walk trough all webparts and search myself. But looks like that the Title is not exposed:

```
Get-PnPWebpart -ServerRelativePageUrl "/default.aspx" | foreach { write-host $_.Title  }
```

Can someone please give me a hint how can I find all web parts with title like `"Issues *"`?

Answer (score 1):

The title property is not there, you need to use `Identity` parameter. However, that doesn't support wildcard search. You need to specify the exact webpart title for it to work like below. It will only provide a single webpart at a time and not a collection :

```
$webparts = Get-PnPWebPart -ServerRelativePageUrl "/Default.aspx" -Identity "Issue Tracking"
```

However, you can use the foreach loop to iterate over the webparts collection and determine the title like:

```
$webparts = Get-PnPWebpart -ServerRelativePageUrl "/default.aspx"
foreach($wp in $webparts)
{
    if($wp.WebPart.Title -like "Issue*")
    {
        #code to remove webpart     
    }
}
```